# Getting bounce rate for specific traffic source with Google Query Explorer

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-query-language

I need help with building a GA call that will provide me with bounce rate for organic traffic. I see how I can build a call that gets an overall bounce rate for all types of traffic:

Metrics:

- gaSessions
- gaBounceRate

Dimensions:

- gaDate

And there I have it:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/ga?ids=ga%xxx&start-date=30daysAgo&end-date=yesterday&metrics=ga%3Asessions%2Cga%3AbounceRate&dimensions=ga%3Adate&segment=sessions%3A%3Acondition%3A%3Aga%3Amedium%3D%3D(none)
```

But now I need to narrow it down to the source of my choice. In my scenario I would like to see the bounce rate numbers for the organic traffic. What would be the Metric for that? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can

- Include dimension "ga:medium" to get the breakdown by all
  channels/media
- filter by ga:medium==organic to get only results for organic traffic
- set segment gaid::-5 (which is the prebuilt segment for organic traffic) to limit the results to organic sessions

Comment: This is perfect. I did everything except the third point (partially because I could not figure out where to put it), and got back all the data I needed. I wonder whether the 3d option is compulsory and I shouldn't be avoiding using it?

Comment: The query explorer has a field "segment", that's where this would go (the query explorer also shows the name of the segment). It is not compulsory, it basically does the same thing as the filter.

Comment: You only need to use one of these. The first will give you a breakdown of traffic by medium (a short list of traffic types, including Organic). The second and third are just two different ways to tell it to only send you the details for Organic traffic, and are both applicable to any other reports that you might request. There's no problem with using more than one at once though.

Comment: Also, I recommend you select this as the correct answer.

Comment: thanks everyone. Just a quick additional question, on how would I select google/organic medium only, using the same techniques? @JBrazier

Comment: You can either include dimension "ga:source", to get a report of all source/medium combinations, or filter by 'ga:source=google' to get only data where your source is Google.